# What does @...@ mean in this Makefile snippet?

Tags: makefile

Can Somebody explain me on short (just as idea) what the following fragment suggests?
- I'm new in C language so I don't understand the meaning of @...@ sign:

```
@SET_MAKE@

VPATH = @srcdir@
pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/@PACKAGE@
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/@PACKAGE@
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/@PACKAGE@
pkglibexecdir = $(libexecdir)/@PACKAGE@
```

or:

```
build_triplet = @build@
host_triplet = @host@
```

If is needed to put more code, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't C. That's a makefile.

Comment: That's definitely not c.  It looks like `make` or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system of using names enclosed in `@` is used by [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/s/autoconf/) to mark strings that should be replaced by the `configure` script.

Answer (score 4):

These appear to be build-system variables of some sort, as the `@` symbol is not (I believe) used in C at all. Considering the names, this seems even more likely. The package and source directory will be inserted in the corresponding places.

Perhaps more interesting are the `$(var)`s, which are used often in Visual Studio project files (but not source, and a VS proj is a make file of sorts itself).

My guess is you have two make/build system variable types being used here. Whether they're from two system, I do not know. As Brian Roach pointed out in a comment, at least GNU autoconf is involved here.

What file did this come from, and what other text surrounds it? That may shed more light, if a well known name is used. It is possible this isn't a code file at all, and just a make file; or it could be a code file with build system variables in (for at-build replace).

Comment: The `$(libdir)` etc. are plain old `make` variables. `configure` usually sets them according to the given prefix and make expands them, much like shell-expansion.

Answer (score 3):

This is not C at all, looks more like a makefile of some sort. Take a look at the filename where you found this, I doubt it ends in `.c`.

Comment: ... and it's not really makefile either, but a makefile template, most probably to be processed with autoconf.